# How to automatically load more data when users reaches at the bottom of the page of the wordpress site?

Tags: pagination

When users scrolls and reaches at the bottom of the page I want to automatically load more data related to it. How to do it in wordpress?

Answer (score 1):

You can run an ajax request when user hits the bottom of the page

```
if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
//your ajax request
}
```

the link to ajax rquest
https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins
for how to add data
https://rudrastyh.com/wordpress/load-more-posts-ajax.html
instead of loadmore button you can paste your ajax request in the if condition